# Access xamp localhost hosted on Azure Vm public

Tags: azure, xampp, virtual-machine

I am having an issue and not able to resolve it.

I have XAMPP instaled on Azure Virtual Machine. I created a virtual host, instead of the localhost/application I am running an app as application.local in the browser. It works fine and it opens a web app.

Now, I am trying to access it over Azure VM public IP address and it doesn't work, any suggestion on what I can do to make it work?

I tried disabling the firewall and it has no luck.

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your application works fine inside the VM, but you can't access the application through the VM public IP address outside. Then you need to check if there is an NSG rule that allows the traffic to the port listening by the application. If no, you need to create one rule for the port.